# ASP.NET Trying to add css class to tr in codebehind

Tags: asp.net

So i have the following method

```
protected void isDirector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlTableRow row = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("today");
```

But getting error

CS0117: 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

EDIT :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="isDirector" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" selected></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:UpdatePanel
<ContentTemplate>

    <tr runat="server" id="test">
        <td>Director First Name:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="DirectorfirstNametxt" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="None" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Director First Name is required." ControlToValidate="DirectorfirstNametxt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </td>
        </tr>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="isDirector" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

I am trying to change the CSS CLASS of TR ID = "test"

Comment: I assume that this is a CheckedChanged-Event handler from a CheckBox inside of a HTML-TableRow. You could try to cast the sender to your CheckBox and it's ParentParent-Control to HtmlTableRow.

Comment: ...therefore you need to make the `tr`'s `runat=server`.

Comment: They are, but I still dont know how I can change the CSSCLASS of the TR in CheckedChanged-Event handler from a CheckBox

Comment: Can you please post complete code, so that we can have better understadining and then we were able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your Checkboxes inside of a HTML-TableRow and you want to set the CSS-Class of the `TR` in the CheckedChanged-Event:

This is an example(note that the `TR`'s have a `runat="server"-tag`):

```
<table>
    <tr ID="TR1" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr ID="TR2" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" OnCheckedChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr ID="test" runat="server">
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" OnCheckedChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

and this is the codebehind:

```
protected void isDirector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var row = (HtmlTableRow)((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent;
    test.Attributes("class") = "CssClass";
}
```

*Edit: if your `tr's` are `runat="server"` and they have unique ID's, you can access them directly*

Comment: I need to reference this TR by ID in the behind

Comment: @StevieB: if they are `runat=server` and have unique ID's you can access the "test"-tr directly via it's ID (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of control is isDirector_CheckChanged tied to - a checkbox?

As the error says, EventArgs is the type of event you're expecting and it doesn't have an 'Item' property. Maybe you're thinking of GridView, Repeater, or other 'item-like' controls?

I'm guessing you're trying to handle the changed event of a checkbox you've put in a repeating/table control. If so, you'll need to handle a Selected or similar event for the repeater that DOES use an EventArgs-derived type with an Item property.

Comment: Its a checkbox yeah, how can I edit the cssClass of a TR when onchange checkbox happens